# Resetting the Work Item Type history in the TFS WorkItem Query-Designer

Tags: tfs, customization, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

Is it possible to reset the work item type history that is proposed to a user who creates a new WorkItem query?

We have some TeamProjects that went through two Process-Template customizations including localization and WorkItem form layout optimizations.

With TFS 2015 we're finally moving to the Agile process template. *The problem is that somewhere the TFS stores the WorkItem-Types you have ever used and displays them in the WorkItem query designer.*

---

[image]

---

The values in the `Work Item Type` are mixed both german and english and are picked from all of the past process templates the team project has ever been configured to use.

Is it possible to reset that list and if so, how?

Comment: Have you deleted the Work Item Type Definitions from TFS? If so, is that something that could be done - you would lose all work items of that type.

Comment: @DaveShaw no, they have been overwritten and renamed

Comment: Do they appear when you do `witadmin listwitd`? You will have to check all team projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the query editor is for all projects in a give collection. When you open the dropdowns, it thus shows all work item types in any of the projects in the collection.

In TFS 2015 we have added a checkbox to scope your query to the existing project. This checkbox is off by default because the majority of the queries run in the scope of a project. When the checkbox is unchecked, the dropdowns are limited to show only the states, fields and work item types that are in use by the existing project.

[image: screenshot of query across projects]

Comment: So, to clean up that list we would have to find the "old" unconverted TeamProject culprit and migrate the process template or use the web UI? The process template "inheritance" mechanism of visual studio online is not yet available in an on premise TFS installation, right?

Comment: If you use TFS 2015 or later, then the checkbox should do all the work to filter out work item types from other projects. If however you are on an older TFS version, then you will need to delete the other work item types from all projects inside the collection.

Comment: This did the trick, we had some projects that haven't been converted yet. We have converted them now and the values in the query filter are consistent. thx

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need these work item types and the work items, you can use `witadmin destroywitd` to destroys the work item types, after running the destroy command, the work item types will disappear from the drop-down. But please notice this will also destroy every work item of that type permanently without recovery.

```
witadmin destroywitd /collection:CollectionURL /p:Project /n:TypeName [/noprompt]
```